# what can be used as an alternative to data.exists

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

Below i am trying to get the value that matches the number input by the user. In the line where there is data.exists, I am getting an error message

> "The getter 'exists' isn't defined for the type 'DataSnapshot'. (Documentation)  Try importing the library that defines 'exists', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'exists"

What is the best solution to it or is there any alternative except of using data.exists ?

```
            var data = await FirebaseDatabase.instance
                .reference()
                .child('Subscribers')
                .orderByChild('number')
                .equalTo(numberPhone)
                .once();

            if (!data.exists) {
              await showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                          title: Text(
                            'Sorry!',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                          ),
                          content: Text(
                            "This Number is already Excite ",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo[900]),
                          ),
                          actions: [
                            // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                            FlatButton(
                                child: Text('Try Again'),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                }),
                            // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                          ]));
              return;
            }
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (c) => OTPController(
                    phoneNumber: _controller.text,
                    codeDigit: dialCodeDigits)));
          },
```

Comment: As an alternative you can check `data.value == null`, but I don't see why `data.exists` wouldn't exist for you as it's clearly defined here: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot-class.html

Comment: Thank you so much. I will do that